# Compile multiple typescript into one closure

Tags: typescript, tsc

When compiling (--out) multiple *.ts files each containing one class with the same module identifier a *.js file is created where each class is wrapped in its own closure and a reference of the module is passed to each closure.

Example:

*Bar.ts:*

```
module baz {export class Bar {}}
```

*Foo.ts:*

```
module baz { export class Foo {}}
```

*out.js*

```
var baz
(function(baz){ var Bar = ... })(baz);
(function(baz){ var Foo = ... })(baz);
```

Is there a way to include both classes into a single file, so that the compiler creates one closure where both classes are declared? Placing all classes in one *.ts file seems to be a really bad idea.

The aim is to:

1. Use one *.ts file per class
2. Use not-exported classes, in all classes of a module
3. Provide a clean interface to the module

Dart-like pseudo code of what I actually mean:

*baz.ts*

```
module baz {
    part "Foo.ts";
    part "Bar.ts";
}
```

*Foo.ts*

```
part of "baz.ts";
export class Foo {}
```

*Bar.ts*

```
part of "baz.ts";
export class Bar {}
```

Thanks for reading,

Martin

Comment: All classes that you declare on the same .ts file will result on a .js with a closure around all defined types. But I don't know how to compile separated .ts files into a unique .js file. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, the sticking point in your question is point 2. If you split your module across multiple files, you will need to export the classes that you want to make available to the other files.

Of course, this also means that consumers will see all of these classes listed, which I understand affects your point about providing a clean interface to the module. The answer to structuring your modules and classes given the constraints will be different depending on your individual circumstances. I tend not to treat modules as wide namespaces, I make them quite narrow and specific, so I would have an `Ajax` module, rather than a `Communication` module with different classes to represent different ways of communicating.